# Drawing sin angle on unit circle

Tags: trigonometry

I am not sure if I am doing the calculation right.

For the angle $a$, $\sin a = -3/4$ for $-\pi < a <-\pi/2$

Here is what I did:

$\sin a = -3/4$

$a1 = \arcsin (-3/4) = -48.590378°$

$\sin a = \sin(180° - a)$

$a2 = (90° - a)$ because $-\pi < a <-\pi/2$, usually it is $180°$ instead of $90°$

$a2 = 90° - (-48.590378°) = 138.590378°$

I am not sure if I am doing the step above correctly.

To draw the line I take the angle of $a$ and put it in $\cos$ to get the $x$ value and then draw the line to the points inside the unit circle.

[image]

Comment: $a2 = -(180^0-48.59^0)$.

Comment: @MathLover I have a question in regards to $−π<a<−π/2$ it doesnt really matter that it is minus right because it is still $180 < a < 90$ right ?

Comment: The absolute value is actually $90 < a <180$ (so between 90 and 180) and for negative value, it would read as $-180 < a < -90$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making that too complicated (and wrong).

Draw the trigonometric circle. Mark the point at ordinate $-\frac34$ on the vertical axis and draw an horizontal line by this point. You meet the circle at two places, pick the one in the third quadrant.

Comment: changed the image to what you described

Comment: I would still assume that you need to do  $a2=−(180−48.59)$  to make sure that you are right

Comment: @zellez: I am right and your figure is fine, trust me.